# import a long tab delimited data file with first row as the header

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, import

Here's a very simple task that I don't seem to be able to get the format right. In short, I am trying to import and format a long tab-delimited txt file, with the first row as the header. I tried the package pgfplotstable with the following codes. As an example, I trimmed the table to include only 2 rows (in addition to the header.) and 5 columns only. Any pointer wiLl be much appreciated ! The error message : Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'AAA' as a floating point number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{table}[h!]\centering
    \pgfplotstableset{
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
        }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=tab, columns/info/.style={string type,column type=r},
        ] {../2.Co-occurrence/demo.txt}
    \caption{Test Data}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here's what demo.txt looks like :

```
Gene1   Gene2   coef    P-val   RRR(test)
AAA BBB 0.44    2.67E-13    4.00E-12
CCC DDD 0.38    8.00E-10    3.12E-08
```

The desired table is included here.[image]

Comment: Welcome! Presumably `column type=r` is responsible for the error? Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: Can you show your `temp.txt` contents?

Comment: you have to add `string type` to `Gene1` and `Gene2` columns.

Comment: I just added what the imported file looks like. Removing column type=r does not help. I think I will need to specify string type for each column? I was hoping for a way to skip specifying each column. if all are treated as text.

Comment: Then you need to add string type as a standalone option to `pgfplotstabletypeset` without the `columns/...` stuff